# windows bat file to linux sh script shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-file, sh

I have windows `batch` code...
I want to run same code on Linux using `sh script shell`

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
color 0a
mode con:cols=68 lines=12

FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%I IN (name.txt) DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%E IN (job.txt) DO echo %%I %%E>name_job.txt & echo name_job: %%I %%E & FOR /F "tokens=*" %%S IN ('notepad job:%%E name:%%I') DO echo %%S>>names\%%I_1.txt
```

**I have this sample.**

```
#!/bin/bash
        for i in $( ls ); do
            echo item: $i
        done
```

Any help would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: You are trying to run the .bat from your linux machine?

Comment: no.i want to make new code..to do same bat windows code..

Comment: convert the windows bat cod to Linux sh shell code

Comment: Would you mind adding what your .bat file does? Some Linux users (me) might not know Windows bat file syntax, and it will be easier to just give you a script to do what you want.

Comment: i have tow files named names.txt job.txt
in names.txt:
Jhon
Mike
Tom
in job.txt:
doctor
engineer
i want to echo on screen
jhon doctor
jhon engineer
Mike doctor
Mike engineer
...
and to do processes every time using script.php like this
./script.php -name Jhon -job Doctor>>name_job.txt
./script.php -name Jhon -job Doctor>>name_job.txt
./script.php -name Mike -job Doctor>>name_job.txt
./script.php -name Mike -job Doctor>>name_job.txt

Comment: sorry for my bad writing..
i have

**1.txt:**
a
b
c
**2.txt**
ww
ss
ddd
fff
**and have script.php
i want bash code to do this command looping 1.txt and 2.txt like this**

**,/script.php -n a -j ww>>n_j.txt**
**,/script.php -n a -j ss>>n_j.txt**
**,/script.php -n a -j ddd>>n_j.txt**
**,/script.php -n a -j fff>>n_j.txt**
**,/script.php -n b -j ww>>n_j.txt**
**,/script.php -n b -j ss>>n_j.txt**
**.**
**.**

Comment: Good lord, I'm fluent in batch and that's hard to read...

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35713640/linux-bash-script-for-loop