# Linux bash script for loop

Tags: linux, bash, batch-file, sh

i have 1.txt 2.txt and script.php

```
1.txt:
a
b
c
d
2.txt
www
rrr
ttt
yyy
```

i want bash file to do this command in Linux:

```
./script.php -n a -j www>>n_j.txt
./script.php -n a -j rrr>>n_j.txt
./script.php -n a -j ttt>>n_j.txt
./script.php -n a -j yyy>>n_j.txt
./script.php -n b -j www>>n_j.txt
./script.php -n b -j rrr>>n_j.txt
./script.php -n b -j ttt>>n_j.txt
.
.
```

i have a bat code working with wondows cmd..i wanna a code like it to work with Linux command line

```
@ECHO OFF


FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%I IN (1.txt) DO FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%E IN (2.txt) DO echo %%I %%E>n_j.txt & echo name_job: %%I %%E & FOR /F "tokens=*" %%S IN ('script.php -n %%I -j %%E') DO echo %%S>>names\n_j.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

arr1=""
arr2=""
mapfile -t arr1 <1.txt
mapfile -t arr2 <2.txt

for i in ${!arr1[@]}; do
        for j in ${!arr2[@]}; do
                ./script.php -n "${arr1[i]}" -j "${arr2[j]}" >>n_j.txt
        done
done
```

`mapfile -t` converts the file to an array, where each line of the file is a new index in the array (-t removes the trailing newline). The for loops iterate over each index of the array, the outer loop going through the lines in the first file, the inner loop going through the lines in the second file, calling script.php with the current array indices.

Comment: I thing you mean `-n "${arr1[i]}" -j "${arr2[j]}"`? What about this: http://pastebin.com/YbCP2GKp?

Comment: The way I have it worked for me, with script.php simply echoing the parameters it received, but my script sends a single parameter, while yours sends 4, which may or may not matter depending on how his actual script.php ends up parsing the parameters. I'll edit to do it your way, since it's more likely to parse it as separate parameters.

Comment: i tried but it gives me this error when i try to open it (sh a.sh)
**: command not found
: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
: command not found
'.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'.sh: line 6: `for arg1 in "${array1[@]}"; do
**

Comment: Don't call the script with sh, that's a different shell interpreter than this code, which is in _bash_. Call the script with `./a.sh` or `bash a.sh`

Comment: # ./a.sh
bash: ./a.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

**********************************

# bash a.sh
: command not found
: No such file or directory
: No such file or directory
: command not found
'.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'.sh: line 8: `for i in ${!arr1[@]}; do

Comment: It is difficult to understand your error messages. Maybe you could paste them at pastebin.com or somewhere else next time. Another thing: Are you using Windows to write this scripts? The `^M` should not be in this line: `/bin/bash^M`. You should switch to unix line endings (*LF* instead of *CRLF*) if you want to use `./a.sh` instead of `bash a.sh`. And which command was not found? `bash`? If `bash` was not found, I would ask whether you are shure that you are working on linux.^^ Or maybe your are using some reduced distribution in an embedded device or something like this?

Comment: thank uuuuu it's work fine now...i open this site from Linux and coded from Linux not from windows..and everything is okay..thank uuu <3

Answer (score 1):

Simply pipe the file in while loop, see if this could help.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read arg1
do
   while read arg2
   do
     ./script.php -n $arg1 -j $arg2 >>n_j.txt
   done<2.txt
done<1.txt
```

Comment: I think you should quote `$arg1` and `$arg2`.

Comment: Also, `while IFS= read -r` is the generally safer choice - even though it doesn't make a difference with respect to the sample data here.

Comment: root@bt:~/Desktop/namebat# sh a.sh

a.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

'.sh: line 7: `   done<2.txt

Comment: Can you show me bash version? 
`$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.`

Comment: I think he did use `sh` instead of `bash`. @SozanMoneer You have to use `bash`. Lets assume the script is called `b.sh`. Write `bash b.sh` or make it executable and run `./b.sh`.